# Selenium WebDriver get child elements of type table of a Div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div element that has a few tables as children. The problem is that I need to scroll in order to get to some tables, so if I use `webElement.getElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='data']"))` I only get the first two elements (all table elements have the same ID).

I need a way to get them all or somehow scroll the div and just keep reading elements.
My selenium version is 2.37.1 I'm using it with Internet Explorer 8. I am not able to provide the code.

```
<div id="statistics" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:hidden;">

<table id="header" width="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0;">    </table>
<table id="data" width="50%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="font-size: 12px;border:1px solid #5c9ccc;"></table>
<div id="separator"></div>
<table id="header" width="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0;"></table>
<table id="data" width="50%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="font-size: 12px;border:1px solid #5c9ccc;"></table>
<div id="separator"></div>
<table id="header" width="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0;"></table>
<table id="data" width="50%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="font-size: 12px;border:1px solid #5c9ccc;"></table>
<div id="separator"></div>
```

Ok, so I managed to get permission to post part of the html. Thats the div that has alot of tables as children. Of those children, i need to read all of the table with id="data"

Comment: This sounds invalid HTML which is a fundamental problem to start with. The [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) **and** [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) **clearly** note ID's *must* be unique. Run your HTML through a validator, and it's going to fail. In terms of the actual problem you've described, three things: are the others in IFrames? Are the others visible & present depending on some sort of action taken on the webpage? Finally, does the problem go away in other browsers?

Comment: the div element that has the tables inside has actually quite a few tables. If I want to see them all, I need to scroll down. I Think my best solution is figuring out a way to scroll down in the div. I see only two elements because only them fit on the page

Comment: Forgot to mention, you are right: the webpage is very very badly made, but it's not made by me so I cannot change it. "Are the others visible & present depending on some sort of action taken on the webpage?" This helped me figure out a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I only get the first two elements (all table elements have the same id).

It's illegal to have multiple elements with same id on same page, that's what classes are for. Id's are meant to be unique. So, edit your id's to make them unique or change the tables into having `class="data"` for instance.

> I am sorry for not being able to provide the code :(

You could possibly use a different expression or just find all children under the div that are of type table, but I am sorry for not being able to provide a better answer due to lack of code.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of debugging and web search, I find the solution to be quite simple: I had to retrieve the parent and call click() on it. after that, calling findElements() returned all the elements I needed.

 if click() is not called, the WebDriver simulates a real user and this would mean getting only two results, the ones that would be normally visible in the page without scrolling.